# Evaluating the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/n!)^m$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

What do we know about the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n!} \right)^m$$

where $m$ is a positive constant integer?

We know when $m = 1$, we get the famous $e$. But I became curious if the series in general for other exponents has been studied before, and whether the sums would converge to a well-known number. Also, does it have any applications in math other than the well-studied case of $m=1$.

Comment: If you type the sums into Wolfram Alpha for certain (maybe all) values of $m$, you get answers in terms of hypergeometric functions... which you will then probably need to Google... :)

Comment: I didn't see this kind of sum. But it looks very interesting. I've tried Wolfarm alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%281%2FFactorial%5Bn%5D%29%5Em%2C%7Bn%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D) and it seems like there is some appearance of Bessel and Hypergeometric functions.

Comment: For $m = 2$, the series sum to $I_0(2)$ where $I_\alpha(x)$ is [modified bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions) of first kind.

Comment: For $m=2$, it is $f(1)$ where $\frac d{dx}(x\frac{df}{dx})=f(x)$ and $f(0)=\frac{df}{dx}(0)=1$.  The differential equation generalises easily, but not its solution.

Comment: As others pointed out, it is hopeless to expect that this sum has an elementary closed form for $m\neq1$.

Answer (score 3):

There is something interesting in $$f_m=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n!} \right)^m$$ For any real $m$, $(m f_m)$ is almost a straight line with a slope very close to $2$ which is the asymptotic value of $f_m$.
$$f_{100}=2+7.89\times 10^{-31}\qquad\qquad
f_{1000}=2+9.33\times 10^{-302}$$

What can be *observed* is that

$$\color{blue}{\log\left(f_m-2\right)\sim -m \log(2)-\frac{3}{40 m}+\frac{\log (2)}{m^2}-\frac{1}{4 m^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^4}\right)}$$  which seems to be decent
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
m & \text{approximation} & \log\left(f_m-2\right) \\
 1 & -0.32500 & -0.33089 \\
 2 & -1.28176 & -1.27445 \\
 3 & -2.03668 & -2.04251 \\
 4 & -2.75192 & -2.76027 \\
 5 & -3.45501 & -3.46163 \\
 6 & -4.15329 & -4.15751 \\
 7 & -4.84933 & -4.85157 \\
 8 & -5.54421 & -5.54503 \\
 9 & -6.23844 & -6.23827 \\
 10 & -6.93229 & -6.93145 \\
 11 & -7.62590 & -7.62461 \\
 12 & -8.31935 & -8.31776 \\
 13 & -9.01269 & -9.01091 \\
 14 & -9.70597 & -9.70406 \\
 15 & -10.3992 & -10.3972 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Since $f_m=2+2^{-m}+6^{-m}+24^{-m}+\cdots$ I expected the first correction term to be $O(3^{-m})$ rather than $O(1/m)$

Comment: @Empy2. Me too, be sure ! Cheers :-)